# Interpretation of gam.vcomp() results (mgcv package, R)

Tags: r, variance, interpretation, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I'm using the `gam.vcomp()` function to obtain the variance explained by each predictor in various GAMs fitted using the mgcv package in R.

```
Gam1 <- gam(presence = s(var1, k=10) + s(var2, k=10) + s(var3, k=10) + var4,
            family=binomial))  

Gam2 <- gam(presence = s(var1, k=10) + s(var2, var3, k=100) + var4, family= binomial))
```

The  variance components returned by `gam.vcomp()` are something like this:

- Gam1: s(var1)= 17,   s(var2) = 14,  s(var3) = 900
- Gam2:  s(var1)= 16,  s(var2,3)= 15

The results for the `Gam1` seem plausible as I know that `var3` is the most important one. I also know the `var2,var3` interaction exists, but am not sure of its importance. The plots of the marginals suggest that the `s(var2, var3)` interaction in model 2 does indeed capture the behaviour of both `s(var2)` and `s(var3)` from model 1, and that the importance of the interaction is sizable.

I am therefore unable to explain why the variance component for the `s(var2, var3)` term is that low, much lower than the `s(var3)` itself. Is there a plausible explanation for this? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

I **think** what's going on is:

In `Gam2`, the statement `s(var2, var3, k=100)` is telling the model to use a single penalty term for `var2` and `var3`, while in `Gam1`, the model is using a penalty term for each variable. If the variables aren't on similar scales (e.g. `var1` is temperature, `var2` is elevation), this could artificially constrain the variance component for `s(var2,var3)`.

If you want to test for a main effect plus a continuous-continuous interaction, I would suggest using `ti(var2,var3)` or `te(var2,var3)` instead of `s(var2,var3)` ([here's a post on the difference between `ti` and `te`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/234817/37420)). Your modified model would look like:

```
    Gam3 <- gam(presence = s(var1) + s(var2) + s(var3) + var4, #Similar to Gam1
          ti(var2,var3), #Tensor product smoother (interaction) between var2 & var3
          family= binomial))
    gam.vcomp(Gam3) #Returns variance components of var1-3, plus var2:3 interaction
```